# How to use DD4T to get content from Tridion and publish using MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tridion, dd4t

I am creating a new application regarding publishing content from Tridion to web using DD4T and MVC3. Can anyone did something like that or have an idea about the same so please it would be of great help to me if one can provide the help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first stop should be the DD4T Project wiki:

- http://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/wiki/TableOfContents?tm=6

Apart from that I find Albert Romkes post very useful to get started:

- http://albertromkes.com/2011/08/24/tridion-and-asp-net-mvc3/

Comment: especially http://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/wiki/41_QuickstartDotNet can be helpful